# Dockerized WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a [official docker distribution](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/) for WSO2 IS? If not, are there any near term plans for such a release?

Answer (score 0):

It is not 'official' , but it is developed by WSO2 :

https://hub.docker.com/r/wso2/is/

Comment: This is no longer available. WSO2 is planning to host WSO2 Docker images in a public Docker registry in the near future.

Comment: Would those be OpenJDK based images?  I understand you pulled the images your had because of Oracle licensing.  Appears there is a private repo docker.wso2.com but I supposed that's only available with a support contract.

Answer (score 0):

@Suresh Currently, WSO2 only ships Dockerfiles for WSO2 products. Please refer [1] for WSO2 IS Dockerfile. The README file has given steps for building the Docker image.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/dockerfiles/tree/master/wso2is

**Update:**

Please find the latest WSO2 Identity Server Dockerfile in the following Git repository:
https://github.com/wso2/docker-is

Comment: Are you referring to the private registry at docker.wso2.com ?  Is that available only with a support contract?

Comment: No, docker.wso2.com can be accessed by creating a WSO2 user account at https://wso2.com/user/register